# Dynamic document "dir" attribue in Nuxt 3's i18n module

Tags: localization, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, vue-i18n, nuxt3

I'm learning Nuxt and its i18n module and facing a bit of an issue, I have the following setup in the module configuration, and switching the locale via `switchLocalePath` doesn't change the layout lang or dir attributes

Searching about this topic(in the context of vue not nuxt) I found out that I have to hook into some callback or watch a reactive value then invoke some logic that sets these values but I was hoping for a more simple solution in Nuxt 3 since the config is already there

```js
i18n: {
    strategy: "prefix",
    defaultLocale: "ar",
    locales: [
      {
        code: "ar",
        iso: "ar",
        name: "العربية",
        file: "ar.json",
        dir: "rtl",
      },
      {
        code: "en",
        iso: "en",
        name: "English",
        file: "en.json",
        dir: "ltr",
      },
    ],
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I had the same problem. just add an HTML tag on your layouts/default.vue or our page for direction and better SEO like this.

```
<template>
   <Html :lang="head.htmlAttrs.lang" :dir="head.htmlAttrs.dir">

    ...the rest of your tags


   </Html>
</template>
<script setup>
const head = useLocaleHead({
  addDirAttribute: true,
  identifierAttribute: 'id',
  addSeoAttributes: true
})
```

2.for  swith between languages

```
  const {
    locale,
    locales
  } = useI18n()
  const switchLocalePath = useSwitchLocalePath()
  const availableLocales = computed(() => {
    return (locales.value).filter(i => i.code !== locale.value)
  })
  const localePath = useLocalePath()
```

the code above generates the availableLocales that it contains the all locals in your nuxt.config except the active language. I like it because it dismisses it and just use locales.value .
make a ul li and nuxt-link

```
<ul-or-ther-loop-tags v-for="locale in availableLocales" :key="locale.code" v-slot="{ active }">
  <li-or-other-tags>
    <NuxtLink :to="switchLocalePath(locale.code)+'/'">
         {{ locale.name }}
    </NuxtLink>
  </li-or-other-tags>
</ul-or-ther-loop-tags>
```

hope solve your problem